# Does Wordpress disable system functions?

Tags: php

One of my plugins reports `base64_encode` as missing. I checked my `php.ini` and know that this function is working before Wordpress loads. Does Wordpress have the habit of disabling functions?

This is the code that checks for the functions:

```
if (!function_exists('base64_decode') || !function_exists('base64_encode')) {
    exit("base64 missing");
}
```

This works if placed before Wordpress loads. The exact same code is run by the plugin and it fails. What could have happened in-between.

Answer (score 0):

WP by itself does not disable those functions. This is a security mechanism of one of your plugins or theme that is disabling them. It is common practice for malicious code to be hidden by encoding it, and then decoding and executing it when the site loads.

You can disable plugins one by one until the function works to determine which one is disabling it. Logically any security related plugins would likely be the one's doing it, and with good reason, i.e. Wordfence, Sucuri, etc.

Comment: Weird. I have zero plugins enabled and switched to the default theme (twentynineteen) and it still disables the function that was enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Well beyond that I would say it's definitely something in your environment then. My guess would be that a different instance of PHP is handling the requests for your WP directory, where the function is disabled in the INI for that instance. Check with your hosting provider, you can verify the location of the INI file in use under WP using phpinfo()